# UILocalNotification iOS5 issue (no alert shown)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uilocalnotification

Is it only me or did Apple break the UILocalNotification mechanism in iOS5 (GM + public release)? It seemed to work fine in the betas but since GM only the sound plays back, no alert is shown (yes I have checked the Notification Settings and the app is all on ON).

I've also made a small separate project (with a brand new app identifier just to be on the safe side), and tested the UILocalNotification class with some very simple code, on the order of:

```
UILocalNotification *singleLocalPush = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

singleLocalPush.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];
singleLocalPush.hasAction = YES;
singleLocalPush.alertBody = @"Alert Body";
singleLocalPush.alertAction = @"Alert Action";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:singleLocalPush];
```

anyone experience similar problems? This is pretty annoying if your app IS about local notifications :)

Best,
Kacper

Comment: Indeed something is broken. I have 5~ alarm apps out there and they are all "broken" right now. Doh.

Comment: see the comments exchanged with hypercrypt  -  this happens when you put an empty string as the alertBody

Comment: Ok my problem might be different because since iOS 5.0 went wild all my apps need to be manually added to alert center in iOS settings by the *user*. Unless they do it no local notifications work (because they are blocked...). Lots of bad reviews..

Comment: I heard this too, apparently this is a problem when you restore apps from a backup made on iOS4 onto iOS5, not sure you can do anything with that...

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure your app is enabled for notifications-

Navigate to Setting->Notifications and make sure your app is enabled.

My app's local notifications work fine on iOS 5, and it was set to be deployed to 3.1.2.